# Error imprimiento con printf

Tags: java

Compañeros buenos días, si me pueden ayudar por favor. Todos los printf me marca como error, no se cual es la razon??? Este programa me servira para saber cuantos elementos de una lista de 5 números enteros son mayores que el promedio.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[5];
    int suma;
    double prom;
    int mayorProm;
    Scanner l = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      System.out.printf("Ingrese elemento[%d]: ", i);
      arr[i] = l.nextInt();
    }

    suma = sumar(arr);
    System.out.printf("Suma =  % d\n", suma);

    prom = suma / (double)arr.length;
    System.out.printf("Promedio = %f\n", prom);

    mayorProm = contarMayorProm(prom, arr);
    System.out.printf("%d elementos son mayores al promedio\n", mayorProm);

  }

  public static int sumar(int[] a) {
    int resultado = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      resultado = resultado + a[i];
    }
    return resultado;
  }

  public static int contarMayorProm(double prom, int[]a) {
    int contador = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i ++) {
      if(a[i] > prom) {
        contador = contador + 1;
      }
    }
    return contador;
  }
}
```

Comment: Qué error te muestra?

Comment: no es println? existe printf?

Comment: Claro que existe! Equivale a `format` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Comment: Si si.. tenes razon.. la documentacion deja mucho que desear en ese sentido...

Comment: Entonces volvamos al inicio, que error te muestra?

Comment: Yo sólo cambio eso de que la clase se llama Main, le pongo un nombre menos problemático con las palabras reservadas y no me sale ningún error en los printf. Eso sí, SonarLint me dice que use %n en vez de \n para que use el fin de línea que corresponda

Comment: The method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)

Comment: Acabo de probar tu programa y funciona perfectamente. Danos un poco más de detalles. ¿Qué versión del JDK estás usando? ¿Qué IDE?, etc.

Comment: Estoy utilizando eclipse

Comment: Tu problema no se replica, así que necesitas añadir más cosas. Versión del JDK, Versión de Eclipse,...

Comment: Te recomiendo que agregues una captura de Eclipse donde se vean los errores

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acuerdo a [esta respuesta aceptada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7774666/236345), el problema estaría en la configuración de Eclipse que usas para compilar tu código.

`Project > Properties > Java Compiler`

Si `Enable project specific settings` no está habilitado, use la opción `Configure Workspace Settings` en ese panel para revisar la configuración global de `Compiler compliance level`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no está al menos en 1.5 o superior, así uses JDK8, la compilación arrojará ese error por como estaba implementada PrintStream en 1.4 y anteriores.

Comment: Gracias compañero estaba en 1.4 pero ya le cambie a 1.5 y ya no me salen esos errores

Comment: @AntonioChamba recuerda aceptar como respuesta la publicación que ayude a solucionar el problema planteado en tu pregunta, revisa [tour] , saludos!

Comment: Me alegra, @AntonioChamba. Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada para que otros sepan que esta es la solución. Y, de paso, procura usar el compliance level acorde al JDK que usas, a menos que tengas un requerimiento no funcional (que el cliente sólo quiera usar java6, cosas así)